# Is there any official Docker image for ThingsBoard Gateway?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, iot, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

Is there any officially supported docker image for ThingsBoard **gateway**?

I only found a [version from "gmatheu"](https://hub.docker.com/r/gmatheu/thingsboard-gateway/) in the Docker Hub, but none in the [official thingsboard repository](https://hub.docker.com/u/thingsboard).

Furthermore I see there is a docker folder (with the Dockerfile) in [thingsboard-gateway github](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard-gateway/tree/60ef596cf90a23ec8186ab7866816ed9ed633f9e) repository: shall I make a docker image out of those files?

Comment: You already have the dockerfile, why not build one by yourself?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing right now, just wanted to know if there was an official distro to save up some time..

Comment: I guess once it have, but the project seems so old, long time no new commit. I guess it's dead, you should ask questions in there github to see what happened, if any replacement project?

Comment: I think they abandoned the idea of using docker starting from release 1.2.1, latest is 2.2.1... I will publish a docker image with 2.2.1 here below

Answer (score 1):

I made a Docker image with resources provided in the official github repository of the project. You can find it [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/abcthings/tbgateway).

You can also find some hints to easily modify the image and customize it for your needs.